# Using pixel widths in responsive css

Tags: css

I find sites responsive even with widths specified in pixels.

```
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/blob/master/src/components/AppBadge/AppBadge.scss#L22
```

Is this bad practice to use widths in pixels in place of percentages when writing responsive
    CSS for web as well as mobile ?

So I was looking for some rule here when can we use pixels as width and when percentage.

Comment: It's obvious. If you have an icon of 25x25 what percentage should use? Impossible to know. Other thing is a question that is better `em` or `px`. However, this should be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: In addition: responsive means the design will adapt to all resolutions modifying the layout, but it's not explicit or implicit the use of percentage measures.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper responsive design usually requires the use of pixels (or some other unit of measurement like `em`,`rem`,`vw`, etc.) as well as percentages and media queries. Most responsive design frameworks like Twitter's Bootstrap still use pixels for their media queries :

```
/* Example of a Bootstrap Media Query */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .visible-lg-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

And handle some of their responsive utility classes rely with percentages and the use of margins/padding :

```
/* Example of Bootstrap's Responsive Column Classes */
.col-xs-1, ... .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
```

So there isn't a hard/fast rule on which to use. Certain scenarios might require percentages, others might want to define an exact size. If you want to do responsive design properly, you'll need to use the best tool available, which may be percentages or it may be pixels.

Comment: `actual responsive utility classes rely on percentages` not completely true. You've missed the negative margins and the possitive paddings are `-15px` and  `15px` respectively. And `.row` is a responsive utility class.... I think

Comment: I've included a reference to paddings / margin as well as the `row` class, which would be considered a responsive-based style.

Comment: Better now :) my upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rem` instead of `px` which utilises the base font size as a reference point if you wanted, which can help with scaling. Personally, I use percentages where possible, but sometimes a design calls for explicitly set widths as being fluid doesn't suit/work at all with the design you've been handed.